# can "default_popup" (in manifest.json field) have full file path?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Im writing chrome extension and I want to use a *.html file as default_popup. the file is located outside my project folder.
I want to write something like:

```
...
"browser_action": 
{
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "..\MembershipApp_v2\build\web\index.html"
},
...
```

but the chrome replies: 
Failed to load extension from: ~\Desktop\6_5_15\plugin_proj
Manifest is not valid JSON. Line: 9, column: 25, Invalid escape sequence.

how can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You cannot traverse up with `..`, or use full paths. It's always relative to the extension root.

After all, when the extension is eventually packaged, it contains only files from its root (where manifest.json is) and down.

I understand the desire to keep some common components in a separate location, but then you need to have some kind of build script that copies them over to the extension's "build" folder.

That said, your error ("invalid **escape sequence**") is related to your use of backslashes. Use forward slashes.